# iOS - Prompt When Navigating From View

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController inside a UITabBarController. The navigationcontroller has a UITableView and a form for editing items. The problem is that if a tab is tapped during editing, the form is just cleared and the user is dumped back to the UITableView.

Is there a way I can add a prompt to confirm navigation away from the edit view?

Comment: I don't understand - what is the "form"? also, do you want a "confirm" alert when the uinavigationcontroller changes views or when the tabbarcontroller changes views. Your post says one thing and the tags another :P

Comment: The "Form" is just another UIViewController which is shown in a segue via the storyboard. Ideally I'll added the prompt on both, but I'd imagine the technique would be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this eventually by using a custom UIBarButtonItem which looks like a back arrow.

Answer (score 1):

First, declare a BOOL in your .h to store the editing state. Also declare a temporary variable we will use later for storing the selected row.

```
BOOL isEditing;
NSUInteger selectedRow;
```

In your viewDidLoad, initialize the boolean to `NO`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // initialization
    isEditing = NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

You can then conform your view controller to `UITextFieldDelegate` and `UIAlertViewDelegate`. The text field delegate allows the controller to receive callbacks when editing ends and begins for the text fields and the alert view delegate allow it to receive callbacks when an alert view is dismissed.

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

You then also need to set all the text field's delegates to be assigned to the controller. So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you add the text fields, just add this:

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

Once you have this, you are all set up to receive callbacks from the text field - so now implement the following two methods like so:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    isEditing = YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    isEditing = NO;
}
```

Now the key here is to make a separate method for pushing the next view, so just do something like this (like you would normally when the table view row is selected):

```
- (void)showNextView {
    // in this method create the child view controller and push it
    // like you would normally when a cell is selected
    // to get the selected row, use the `selectedRow` variable
    // we declared earlier.
}
```

You now need to implement the table view callback when the user selects a row - in this method we test if they are editing and show them a prompt if they are. If they aren't, we go to the next view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedRow = [indexPath row];

    if (isEditing) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                     initWithTitle:@"Continue Editing?"
                     message:@"Continue Editing or discard edits"
                     delegate:self
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Discard"
                     otherButtonTitles:@"Continue"];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return;
    }
    [self showNextView];
}
```

Finally, we need to implement the alert view delegate callback for when the alert view is dismissed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) return; // stay editing
    [self showNextView];
}
```

Hope that all makes sense and is helpful to you!

Comment: But I'm using a storyboard, so the edit controller has no knowledge as far as I can see that it's inside a parent viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a UINavigationController, if you are pushing this "form" onto the stack you could set

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
```

That way the tab bar would be hidden until they are done with the form.